# Rails - NoMethoderror: Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, belongs-to

I am making a project  which will allow Users to select the Events they are participating in, following BinaryThistle's tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNrNGTe2Zqk)

Upon entering the '/users/1/edit' I receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#edit
undefined method `userevents' for #<User:0x0000000c31f450>
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `edit'
```

I can view '/users/1' properly without any error. I have also tried restarting my server and running rake db:migrate.

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

helper_method :current_user

def show

end

def edit
    @all_events = Event.all
    @user_events = current_user.userevents.build
end

def update
    redirect_to current_user
end   
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['user.provide.capitalize']
        user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
        user.school = nil
        has_many :userevents
        has_many :events, :through => :userevents
        user.save!
        user
    end
end
end
```

userevent.rb

```
class Userevent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :userevents
has_many :users, :through => :userevents
end
```

Please help!

Comment: I believe both `has_many` clauses in `user.rb` should be moved out of class method to the class definition itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `has_many :userevents` in your `User` class.

Comment: Thanks! Worked out for me!

Answer (score 1):

Place both has_many relation outside the method.
Write it just below this line  "class User < ActiveRecord::Base".
Hope that work for you

Comment: Ah, that clarifies where I was supposed to place them. Thanks!